# inline nested list, keeping main list on top

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I guess the title isn't the best, but I have an issue with two nested list, the first one is inline and extends the second one when clicked. The second one is  a regular list.

My issue is that I like to keep the main list on in a row even when an other list is expanded, now the second item in the first list is moved down.

Here is the code:

```css
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-box + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.toggle-box + label + div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-box + label:before {
  background-color: #4F5150;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <input class="toggle-box" id="header2" type="checkbox">
        <label for="header2">Math</label>
        <div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled nav nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sum')">
                        <img src="Pictures/sumicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Sum
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('multi')">
                        <img src="Pictures/multiplicationicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Multiplication
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('divition')">
                        <img src="Pictures/divitionicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Divition
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sub')">
                        <img src="Pictures/subicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Substraction
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="toggle-box" id="header3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="header3">Math</label>
        <div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled nav nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sum')">
                        <img src="Pictures/sumicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Sum
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('multi')">
                        <img src="Pictures/multiplicationicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Multiplication
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('divition')">
                        <img src="Pictures/divitionicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Divition
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sub')">
                        <img src="Pictures/subicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Substraction
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can also been seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6wv2u0z9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add vertical-align:top to the existing CSS:

```
.list-inline>li {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}
.toggle-box + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.toggle-box + label + div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  display: block;
}
.toggle-box + label:before {
  background-color: #4F5150;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
.list-inline>li {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <input class="toggle-box" id="header2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="header2">Math</label>
    <div>
      <ul class="list-unstyled nav nav-list">
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sum')">
            <img src="Pictures/sumicon.png" height="20" width="20">Sum
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('multi')">
            <img src="Pictures/multiplicationicon.png" height="20" width="20">Multiplication
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('divition')">
            <img src="Pictures/divitionicon.png" height="20" width="20">Divition
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sub')">
            <img src="Pictures/subicon.png" height="20" width="20">Substraction
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="toggle-box" id="header3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="header3">Math</label>
    <div>
      <ul class="list-unstyled nav nav-list">
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sum')">
            <img src="Pictures/sumicon.png" height="20" width="20">Sum
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('multi')">
            <img src="Pictures/multiplicationicon.png" height="20" width="20">Multiplication
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('divition')">
            <img src="Pictures/divitionicon.png" height="20" width="20">Divition
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sub')">
            <img src="Pictures/subicon.png" height="20" width="20">Substraction
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is better to add some fixed width to the items as well, so that it doesn't move the second item when the first item is expanded.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to add the property `vertical-align: top` to the `li` element. You can do that as mentioned below :

```
.list-inline > li {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It would be better if you can add some width to the list elements as well so that they don't displace when the nested menu's are expanded. Just to give an example, as below :

```
.list-inline > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 150px;  /*Add this as well*/
}
```

See this below :

```css
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-box + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.toggle-box + label + div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-box + label:before {
  background-color: #4F5150;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

.list-inline > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <input class="toggle-box" id="header2" type="checkbox">
        <label for="header2">Math</label>
        <div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled nav nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sum')">
                        <img src="Pictures/sumicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Sum
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('multi')">
                        <img src="Pictures/multiplicationicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Multiplication
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('divition')">
                        <img src="Pictures/divitionicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Divition
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sub')">
                        <img src="Pictures/subicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Substraction
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="toggle-box" id="header3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="header3">Math</label>
        <div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled nav nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sum')">
                        <img src="Pictures/sumicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Sum
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('multi')">
                        <img src="Pictures/multiplicationicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Multiplication
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('divition')">
                        <img src="Pictures/divitionicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Divition
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="vm.SelectTool('sub')">
                        <img src="Pictures/subicon.png" height="20" width="20"> Substraction
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```